# How to setup users with email: user@usersdomain.com in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email

I have a requirement which is to allow users to buy a domain through my site and then programatically set them up with email accounts at that domain, eg user1@domain.com user2@domain.com, etc.

To integrate the buying of the domain I'm planning on using a domain reseller like [this](http://www.srsplus.com/reseller-tools/api.shtml).

The next step - of creating the email accounts - is where I'm floundering currently. I'm assuming I can programatically set the domain name to point where ever I need for the email pointers, but not sure how to programatically setup the email client on the other end. I don't care so much what the email client is - gmail, etc. Ideally I'd be able to brand it a bit, but it's not absolutely required.

Hoping someone has experience with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Andrew - You appear to have accidentally made two nearly identical accounts. Please flag this question for moderator attention if you would like to have them merged.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to choose a mail server for your system. Then you **get the SDK of this server** and create with the provided interfaces users from your user interface.

For example, a basic free mail server is MailEnable that plesk also use for the same reason.

on this page you can get the sdk of the MailEnable mail server

http://www.mailenable.com/developers.asp

and there you can find the api to control it from your asp.net pages.

Hope this helps you to start.

Comment: Thanks, I'd considered going that route with a similar product, but I'm aiming for a 3rd party service I could just tie into with an API, rather than having to host and implement it all myself. Any ideas?

Comment: @andrew I think is the same way, this api, have an sdk, an way to call it.